# Trimming whitespaces in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex for parsing key/values pairs separated by the equal sign. There can be some whitespaces characters before and after the '=', but key and values should be without them. For example

```
key=value
key = value
```

must return the same result: 'key' and 'value', not 'key ' and ' value'.

I have a little problem with parsing the value, because it can be empty and it's ok.

```
key=
```

Here is my version of regex, without trimming whitespaces of the value https://regex101.com/r/pY9rW8/2

Comment: this  https://regex101.com/r/pY9rW8/3 ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `string.Trim()` ?

Comment: I'm lazy. string.Replace(" = ","=");  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match the spaces in the value part with `[\t ]*`

```
^\s*([^#]\S+?)\s*=[\t ]*(.*)
```

or

```
^\s*([^#]\S+?)\s*=[\t ]*(.*?)\s*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pY9rW8/4)

Answer (score 3):

You could consider a variant without regular expressions:

```
string s = "key=value";
var a = s.Split('=');
var key = a[0].Trim();
var val = a[1].Trim();
```

Comment: Of course, additional checks would need to be done if there is no value. But, solid solution.

Comment: Nice solution, but the goal was use regex to make it

Answer (score 0):

You can also use named group on the key and the value and throw away the blank space :

> [`^(?<key>.+)\s*=\s*(?<value>.+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/pY9rW8/5)

Comment: It doesn't work with an empty value, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You gave this regex:

```
^\s*([^#]\S+?)\s*=(.*)
```

This doesn't take whitespace after the `=` into account. To do so, add another `\s*`:

```
^\s*([^#]\S+?)\s*=\s*(.*)
```

Also, presumably you want to match the end of the string, seeing as you're matching the beginning via `^`, so add a `$` at the end:

```
^\s*([^#]\S+?)\s*=\s*(.*)$
```

Here's a live example:

https://regex101.com/r/pY9rW8/6

Comment: Your example doesn't work correctly when the value is empty. It considers next string as a value